# Equal height elements, bottom-aligned within a flexbox container, pure CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

These are the requirements:

1. Using `display:flex` for the parent element
2. Elements' text within flex-container must align bottom; i.e. when a line of copy breaks to two or three or more lines, other sibling elements should still be vertically-aligned to the end of the main.
3. No javascript or `overflow:hidden` hacks.

The parent container is a plain block-level element, like a div.

Inner markup is flexible but needs to contain links and a bottom border, but I'd prefer to avoid over-nesting.

Thus far I've been able to keep the child elements bottom-aligned using `align-self: flex-end`, but the heights are not the same. I can equalize the height by removing this attribute and just leaving it `flex:1` but this does not vertically align bottom.

Here is a codepen with what I've got so far (detailed below): http://codepen.io/oomlaut/pen/ZQJdZP. Any help is appreciated, as admittedly I do not have subject-matter mastery of flex-box yet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.flexcontainer {
  position:relative;
  outline: 1px dashed #333;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:1em;
  background:blue;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

}
.flexitem {
  width:25%;
  padding:1em;
  display:flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-self: flex-end; /* <--- removing this will normalize heights but remove vertial align:bottom */
}
.flexcontainer a{
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  background:gray;
}
.flexcontainer a:hover{
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <a class="flexitem" href="#">Link1</a>
  <a class="flexitem" href="#">Another Link2</a>
  <a class="flexitem" href="#">Link3</a>
  <a class="flexitem" href="#">Link4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is :

```
  align-items: flex-end;
```

and not

```
  align-self: flex-end;
```

because you want to align content, not the container itself ;)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwxmBa

Comment: Is there in-depth documentation of the properties and values? I've read the [w3c docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), as well as the tuts on [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and  [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) but would never have dowsed that to be the case!